# Git command for install docker engine in git lab or git hub

Tags: git, docker, github, gitlab

Can we using git lab to install docker engine without using AWS? IS there any git command to install docker engine so we can use to make containers or build images?

I am expecting the proper answers with explanation in details that why and how .

Comment: I do not think git provides anything related to docker... at least, not git from upstream. To back this statement, I ran `git help docker` and got `No manual entry for gitdocker`.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Docker image by adding a build step for you gitlab pipeline.
Inside your `.gitlab-ci.yml`

```
stages:
  - build

variables:
  IMAGE_TAG: $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE/<project-name>:$CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG

build:
  image: docker:latest
  services:
  # Docker inside docker
    - docker:dind
  stage: build
  before_script:
    - docker login -u $CI_REGISTRY_USER -p $CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD $CI_REGISTRY
  script: 
  # <registry URL>/<namespace>/<project>/<image>
  # Will create an image with the name of the branch
    - docker build -t $IMAGE_TAG .
    - docker images
    - docker push $IMAGE_TAG
```

This will create an image based on the top commit of the branch you are pushing. After that the image will be available in the container register on Gitlab. Not 100% sure this is what you are looking for, but hope it helps.